# Android: How to know where the app is running

Tags: android

There is some way to know if my Android app is running on debugger or on a phone?.
I want to check some variable, property, or something like that to know where the app is running to prevent some crash when I call some 3rd applications (not available on debugging time)

Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html)

You can access logs, threads and heap information. also check running apps and services. You can also simulate phone behaviours on the emulator, like an incoming call, as an example. Well, I would also recommend reading all the information in the [debugging](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html) section, there are a lot of useful tools available for Android developers.

Answer (score 0):

You mean detecting the emulator? Because you can run under debugger also on your device.

Use this to detect the emulator (worked for me a while ago):

```
"google_sdk".equals(Build.MODEL)
```